# Facebook restore deleted app, using same for authentication in android app

Tags: android, ios, facebook

I need help/suggestion to restore my deleted Facebook app. Please do not mark it offtopic.

I know i can create new app in 2-5 mins. and replace the old details with new one and can go ahead.I can easily do it on website.

But the problem is i am using the same appId for Facebook authentication in my IO and Android  apps.The apps is having 100,000 - 500,000 installation on android. Some features in app will work only after Facebook authentication.

Can i create new app and update it with old appId & app secret ?

I would like to know is there any suggestion / thought which will help me proceed in this matter.

Thanks for help!
VK

Answer (score 0):

> Can i create new app and update it with old appId & app secret ?

No unfortunately you can't

Comment: Thanks for reply. From the link you gave, i got link for appeal page  https://developers.facebook.com/appeal  -- which is showing message "Currently, none of your apps are restricted."